# AngularJS: How to provide independent communication between multiple instances of the same 2 controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers allocated to two views:

**[ResultsView ng-controller="ResultsCtrl"]
[SearchView ng-controller="SearchCtrl"]**

The Search View has many complex filters/options and is filled in by the user, then he/she can press "Search" on SearchView and Results should be populated into a Grid.

Now I can send information between two either by a **Service** or by using **$rootScope.$broadcast**.

---

Heres the problem I've run into:

**[ResultsView ng-controller="ResultsCtrl"][SearchView ng-controller="SearchCtrl"]**
**[ResultsView ng-controller="ResultsCtrl"][SearchView ng-controller="SearchCtrl"]**
**[ResultsView ng-controller="ResultsCtrl"][SearchView ng-controller="SearchCtrl"]**

If I were to have **multiple** **Result-Search** sections on the same page, how can I ensure they each act independently from each other? Using the Service approach, the ResultsCtrl and SearchCtrl both have the defined service

```
.controller("searchCtrl", ["$scope", "$searchHttp", function ($scope, $searchHttp) {
.controller("resultsCtrl", ["$scope", "$searchHttp", function ($scope, $searchHttp) {
```

So I can't change how each instance of the controller behaves regarding the service. Soon as one **SearchCtrl** calls the service, it will modify every **ResultsCtrl** instance.

Likewise using broadcasts **$rootScope.$broadcast("searchResults"...** will be picked up by every **ResultsCtrl** instance.

So whats the best way around this? I want to reuse the Results and Search View code since its basically the same. But I need to render each pair independently on the same page a few times.

Answer (score 1):

I think the HTML structure you need is something like this.

```
<!--First-->
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ResultsCtrl">
    </div>
</div>

<!--Second-->
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ResultsCtrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

This HTML structure would help you to use independently the search results one's parent SearchCtrl created in ResultsCtrl.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/zp82e3xm/3/) is here.
I hope this would help you. :)

Comment: I did not realise you could do this. Is this the right way to go around it? I mean the inner controllers don't know what scope variables are available in the parent ones until they actually execute.

Comment: I also think this is *NOT* the right way in all cases as you mentioned. But If you always use ResultsCtrl in SearchCtrl, this solution could work anway. If you insist some best practice, I would recommend to write the directive for rendering the results of SearchCtl instead of ResultsCtrl. The directives could get parameter from any parent controller. Enjoy!